# Git push and update gh-pages in the future

Tags: git, github, automation, github-pages, github-api

I have some changes for a website that I want to be released at 9:00 AM PT tomorrow. I want the changes to be commented out until then.

I have commit 1 (commented out code) and commit 2 (uncommented out code). I currently have commit 1 pushed and I want commit 2 at 9:00 AM PT tomorrow (which should update my github pages automatically within the minute). How can I automate pushing this with github?

Comment: you don't automate with github: github is the receiver, I guess. Also _git is not github_. I'd write a batch script with a git push and set it up to be run at 9AM tomorrow.

Comment: `cron` on linux/unix or `at` (scheduled tasks) on Windows.

Comment: @DaemonPainter fair enough I could use something like `cron` for that intent (and ik git≠github lol i added github tag to clarify this is a github specific q). But I know you can change commit dates and was hoping that if I commit with some time in the future, it would work like that? If `git commit -m "message" --date "Tue Feb 09 09:00:00 2021 +0300"` doesnt change the date then I guess there's no answer for this :.(

Comment: yes, but not for your intent: the date is just metadata. I assume with GitHub pages, as soon as the commit is present, then your update is published. The system doesn't really check for date consistency, at least git doesn't. GitHub Pages might, if this is that specific, but I doubt it.